# Working with Bluetooth

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I'm using [32feet.NET](http://32feet.net/) library for my project, my project is to control a robot using bluetooth protocol. I have to send a char or maybe array of chars as an instruction but unfortunately I'm not familiar with `32feet.NET` (I can just find all bluetooth devices and send a pairing request to any of them so far ) and there is no good Instruction manual on [Library support site](http://32feet.net/) Could anyone please help me to do basic send/receive operations so I can move forward myself with more complex tasks?

Comment: Step1. Ask more specific question.

Comment: I believe you can ask at the vendor's forum - http://32feet.net/forums/

Answer (score 2):

Here is  an example for connection

```
BluetoothAddress addr = new BluetoothAddress(0x0016756A4CD1);
BluetoothEndPoint ep = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, BluetoothService.DialupNetworking);
BluetoothClient cln = new BluetoothClient();
cln.Connect(ep);
```

(*DialupNetworking is just an example. You should find in your Robot's manuals which service to connect to*) After that you can send and receive bytes using `GetStream()` method of  `BluetoothClient`.

```
byte[] buf = .....
cln.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

But what you should send or receive is device-specific and you should read the manuals of your robot.

For example after connecting to `DialupNetworking` service of a cell phone you can use `AT command set` to send/read SMSs

Answer (score 0):

Try http://32feet.codeplex.com/documentation and http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=General%20Bluetooth%20Data%20Connections -- these should get you started.

Comment: Do i have to create a Virtual Serial port or i can do my work only using BluetoothClient ?

Comment: No need for `Virtual Serial port`. You can work only using BluetoothClient.

Comment: how to send and receive array of chars using BluetoothClient ? i can send a file using BluetoothClient but i have no idea about array of chars !